# What tools can I use to find Part Of Speech Patterns

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, part-of-speech

I am looking for tools to find Part Of Speech patterns on a corpus of documents. I am using the Stanford NLP tools for POS tagging my documents. Now I would like to query these tagged documents and find some specific POS patterns such as for example

**NP** is **JJ**  (ex:  the movie is nice)

or **JJ** **NP**  (ex : excellent foie gras)

Is there a tool that can do this for me in a simple and efficient manner or do I need to write my own ?

Comment: up voted! very useful question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Stanford CoreNLP, you can also use TokensRegex to match a pattern in a list of tokens: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokensregex.shtml

For example, your two patterns would be something like:

[{tag:NN}] [{word:is}] [{tag:JJ}]

[{tag:JJ}] [{tag:NN}]

(Side note, but NP is not a POS tag. Likely, really, what you want is [{tag:/N.*/}] and [{lemma:be}] to catch a broader range of cases).

Comment: Excellent. I was looking at TokensRegex at the same time you answered. I thought NP was NounPhrase but indeed .. its does not exist :) Thanks for the clarification, and thanks for the lemma trick ! Testing this right away.

Comment: shouldnt 'tag' be 'pos' in your answer ? I was looking at this paper http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/tokensregex-tr-2014.pdf where they mention pos:"NNP"  --> token POS is abc

Comment: also as a side question how would I capture Noun Phrases the same way I am capturing Nouns (NN). For eample "the tomato salad was wonderful" how can I capture "tomato salad" + "was" + "wonderful"  and not just "salad"+"was"+"wonderful" ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: There's a chance "pos" is aliased to "tag" -- a historic property of CoreNLP is that "tag" is taken to mean POS tag (I guess at one point it was the only tag).

I don't think there's a simple way of capturing noun phrases that doesn't require a constituency parse, but a decent heuristic is to look for a pattern like [{tag:/[NJDC].*/}]* [{tag:/N.*/}]. This will take a (potentially empty) sequence of nouns, adjectives, determiners, or numbers; followed by a noun at the end.

Answer (score 1):

One tool to consider is the Corpus Workbench: http://cwb.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, this tool looks great but do you know if I can use it with the stanford POS annotations (i think it's Penn Treebank). I have already annotated the corpus and ideally I would like to directly query this annotated corpus without generating a new set of annotations. Do you know if this tool will let me do this ?

Comment: No, I think you'd have to convert the annotation to a different format, so the Stanford tool in Gabor's answer sounds better for your purposes.